# Inserting page causes master to center\resize

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

When I insert a page or pagination changes within my book, the headers\footers set in my masters center on the spread. The error does not occur when I insert a page that does not have a text box for the main content of my page. When I reapply my master an error pops up that the page size of my doc has changed from the master. It also does not occur when in pages that I did not build. I've gone over my page settings with a colleague and nothing appears to be different. I've tried saving as an IDML and the error persists. Hoping that there is something stupid that I missed.

Comment: Did you try creating a brand new document with master pages and the same master items? If it does the same thing, it's your ID prefs. If it doesn't, it's your document, and you'll need to extract the content and recreate it. Sometimes documents just corrupt.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to work out of a template that I know is good. I'm building my headers from scratch, using completely different text and its still doing it. I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: Also: I was just looking at it with my colleague again and we got it narrowed down to being something that is effecting the text boxes with or without text in them and the problem occurred on her machine as well so it's not something local to me.

Comment: If you can provide a link to the template and/or part of your book, I'll take a look at it. It does sound like the template has a hidden problem that you're surfacing by adding headers and footers. Indicate in your question which version of ID you're using.